# WSDL client return wrong date in entity

Tags: java, wsdl

I have a wsdl client, the problem is with one of the methods that returns an entity, this entity have a Date type and always subtract one day from the date.

The field in the entity is defined like this:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected Date intDate;
```

In the backend the field is defined like this:

```
@Column(name = "int_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date intDate;
```

If in the database the date is '2022-01-10' the value returned in the client is 'Sun Jan 09 21:00:00 UYT 2022' (printed with toString())

Whats wrong with the conversion?

The code of the client was generated with the command wsimport

Comment: What's the data type of the column in the database?  It looks to me like the value stored in the database is being interpreted somewhere along the way as a UTC date, in which case it is being read correctly.  You could try using `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` as the database time zone; or you could try reading the date into a `LocalDate` object.  Without knowing what's going on in your database, it's hard to know which of those will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The database is mysql, the type of the column is 'date'. I cant use localdate because is java 6.
I will try with TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE